# push arrays into an empty array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to code a function to get parent's children. `get_children` supposed to return an array of `$this_parent_id` children.

```
/* $pages array */

Array
(
    [0] => Pages Object
        (
            [id_page] => 1
            [str_title] => index
            [id_parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => Pages Object
        (
            [id_page] => 10
            [str_title] => download
            [id_parent] => 0
        )

    [2] => Pages Object
        (
            [id_page] => 11
            [str_title] => about us
            [id_parent] => 1
        )

    [3] => Pages Object
        (
            [id_page] => 12
            [str_title] => contact us
            [id_parent] => 1
        )

    [4] => Pages Object
        (
            [id_page] => 13
            [str_title] => members
            [id_parent] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to push child arrays into an array when condition is true.

```
print_r(get_children(1, $pages));
function get_children($this_parent_id, $family) {
    foreach($family as $page) {
        if ($page->id_parent == $this_parent_id) {
            /* here I need to append $page to $temp_array
        isset($temp_array) ? $temp_array = array($temp_array, (array)$page) : $temp_array = (array)$page; */
        }
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
```

Comment: Like `$this_parent_id[]=$page`?

Comment: changed to `isset($temp_array) ? $temp_array[] =(array)$page : $temp_array = (array)$page;` and works. thanks @AlvinWong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print_r(get_children(1, $pages));
function get_children($this_parent_id, $family)
{
    global $temp_array;
    foreach ($family as $page) {
        if ($page->id_parent == $this_parent_id) {
            isset($temp_array) ? $temp_array[] = (array) $page : $temp_array = array((array) $page);
        }
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `array_push()` the function you are looking for?

```
function get_children($this_parent_id, $family) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    foreach($family as $page) {
        if ($page->id_parent == $this_parent_id) {
            array_push($temp_array, $page);
        }
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but doesnt work.  `First argument should be an array in`, while $temp_array is array when i do print_r

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because of the assignment in the line

```
isset($temp_array) ? $temp_array = array($temp_array, (array)$page) : $temp_array = (array)$page;
```

the following function code should work just fine.

```
function get_children($this_parent_id, $family)
{
   $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($family as $page) {
        if ($page->id_parent == $this_parent_id) {
            array_push($temp_array,$page);
        }
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
```